# Why will it only print the banner, and hangs/times out on results? - - Python3 (sockets, sys)

Tags: python, python-3.x, sockets

Trying to build a simple SMTP tool to VRFY user. Not getting the desired output.

Not sure if it is an encoding issue or if I'm missing something super simple, or if there is a simpler way around this problem.

Please help :)

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import sys
import socket


if len(sys.argv) != 3:
    print('[*] Usage: smtpvrfy.py <ip> <username>')

ip = sys.argv[1]
username = sys.argv[2]

print('SMTP TOOL')
print(25 * '-')

s=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
connect = s.connect((ip,25))
banner = s.recv(1024)
print(banner)
s.send((b'VRFY ') + username.encode('utf-8'))
results = s.recv(1024)
print(results)
s.close() 

------

the output is as follows:

------

SMTP TOOL
-------------------------
b'220 hotline.localdomain ESMTP Postfix\r\n'
b'421 4.4.2 hotline.localdomain Error: timeout exceeded\r\n'
```

Answer (score 0):

due to encoding/decoding issues. This fixed it!

````
connect = s.connect((ip,25))
banner = s.recv(1024).decode()
print(banner)
s.send(b'VRFY %s\n' % str(sys.argv[2]).encode())
results = s.recv(1024).decode()
print(results)
s.close()```
````

Comment: I'm pretty sure that it was the lack of a newline character to terminate the command that was the problem, rather than anything involving encoding.

Comment: I do note, you are correct here, the only thing the .decode() was getting rid of the byte chars in the output, thanks for explaining!